# Implementing cross-DAG dependency in Apache airflow

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am trying to implement DAG dependency between 2 DAGs say A and B. DAG A runs once every hour and DAG B runs every 15 mins.

1. Each time DAG B starts it's run I want to make sure DAG A is not in running state.
2. If DAG A is found to be running then DAG B has to wait until DAG A completes the run.
3. If DAG A is not running, DAG B can proceed with it's tasks.

DAG A :

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'dependency',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 9, 10, 10, 1),
    'email': ['xxxx.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

with DAG('DAG_A', schedule_interval='0/60 * * * *',max_active_runs=1, catchup=False,
         default_args=default_args) as dag:

    task1 = DummyOperator(task_id='task1', retries=1, dag=dag)
    task2 = DummyOperator(task_id='task2', retries=1, dag=dag)
    task3 = DummyOperator(task_id='task3', retries=1, dag=dag)

    task1 >> task2 >> task3
```

DAG B:

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'dependency',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 9, 10, 10, 1),
    'email': ['xxxx.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

with DAG('DAG_B', schedule_interval='0/15 * * * *',max_active_runs=1, catchup=False,
        default_args=default_args) as dag:

    task4 = DummyOperator(task_id='task4', retries=1, dag=dag)
    task5 = DummyOperator(task_id='task5', retries=1, dag=dag)
    task6 = DummyOperator(task_id='task6', retries=1, dag=dag)

    task4 >> task5 >> task6
```

I have tried using ExternalTaskSensor operator. I am unable to understand if the sensor finds DAG A to be in success state it triggers the next task else wait for the task to complete.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [ExternalTaskSensor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/sensors/external_task/index.html) to achieve what you are looking for. The key aspect is to initialize this sensor with the correct `execution_date`, being that in your example the `execution_date` of the last `DagRun` of **DAG_A**.
Check this example where **DAG_A** runs every 9 minutes for 200 seconds.  **DAG_B** runs every 3 minutes and runs for 30 seconds. These values are arbitrary and only for demo purpose, could be pretty much anything.

DAG A (nothing new here):

```py
import time
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models.baseoperator import chain
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago


def _executing_task(**kwargs):
    print("Starting task_a")
    time.sleep(200)
    print("Completed task_a")


dag = DAG(
    dag_id="example_external_task_sensor_a",
    default_args={"owner": "airflow"},
    start_date=days_ago(1),
    schedule_interval="*/9 * * * *",
    tags=['example_dags'],
    catchup=False
)
with dag:

    start = DummyOperator(
        task_id='start')

    task_a = PythonOperator(
        task_id='task_a',
        python_callable=_executing_task,
    )

chain(start, task_a)
```

DAG B:

```py
import time
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.utils.db import provide_session
from airflow.models.dag import get_last_dagrun
from airflow.models.baseoperator import chain
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.sensors.external_task import ExternalTaskSensor


def _executing_task():
    time.sleep(30)
    print("Completed task_b")


@provide_session
def _get_execution_date_of_dag_a(exec_date, session=None,  **kwargs):
    dag_a_last_run = get_last_dagrun(
        'example_external_task_sensor_a', session)
    print(dag_a_last_run)
    print(f"EXEC DATE: {dag_a_last_run.execution_date}")
    return dag_a_last_run.execution_date


dag = DAG(
    dag_id="example_external_task_sensor_b",
    default_args={"owner": "airflow"},
    start_date=days_ago(1),
    schedule_interval="*/3 * * * *",
    tags=['example_dags'],
    catchup=False
)
with dag:

    start = DummyOperator(
        task_id='start')

    wait_for_dag_a = ExternalTaskSensor(
        task_id='wait_for_dag_a',
        external_dag_id='example_external_task_sensor_a',
        allowed_states=['success', 'failed'],
        execution_date_fn=_get_execution_date_of_dag_a,
        poke_interval=30
    )
    task_b = PythonOperator(
        task_id='task_b',
        python_callable=_executing_task,
    )

chain(start, wait_for_dag_a,  task_b)
```

We are using the param `execution_date_fn` of the `ExternalTaskSensor` in order to obtain the `execution_date` of the last DagRun of the **DAG_A**, if we don't do so, it will wait for **DAG_A** with the same `execution_date` as the actual run of **DAG_B** which may not exists in many cases.

The function `_get_execution_date_of_dag_a` does a query to the metadata DB to obtain the exec_date by using `get_last_dagrun` from Airflow models.

Finally the other important parameter is `allowed_states=['success', 'failed']` where we are telling it to wait until **DAG_A** is found in one of those states (i.e if it is in `running` state will keep executing poke).

Try it out and let me know if it worked for you!.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way you can achieve that in "general" way is to use some external locking mechanism

You can achieve quite a good approximation though using pools:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.3/concepts.html?highlight=pool

if you set pool size to 1 and assign both dag A and B to the pool, only one of those can be running at a time. You can also add priority_weight in the way that you see best - in case you need to prioritise A over B or the other way round.