# Airflow ExternalTaskSensor with different scheduler interval

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Currently I have two DAGs: DAG_A and DAG_B. Both runs with `schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1)`

DAG_A has a Task1 which usually takes 7 hours to run. And DAG_B only takes 3 hours.

DAG_B has a `ExternalTaskSensor(external_dag_id="DAG_A", external_task_id="Task1")` but also uses some other information X that is generated hourly.

What is the best way to increase the frequency of DAG_B so that it runs at least 4 times a day? As far as I know, both DAGs must have the same schedule_interval. However, I want to update X on DAG_B as much as I can.

---

One possibility is to create another DAG that has a ExternalTaskSensor for DAG_B. But I don't think it's the best way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, your conditions are:

- Keep running *DAG_A* daily
- Run *DAG_B* *n* times a day
- Every time DAG_B runs it will wait for *DAG_A__Task_1* to be completed

I think you could easily adapt your current design by instructing `ExternalTaskSensor` to wait for the desired execution date of *DAG_A*.

From the [ExternalTaskSensor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/sensors/external_task/index.html#module-airflow.sensors.external_task) operator defnition:

> Waits for a different DAG or a task in a different DAG to complete for a specific execution_date

That `execution_date` could be defined using `execution_date_fn` parameter:

> execution_date_fn (Optional[Callable]) – function that receives the current execution date as the first positional argument and optionally any number of keyword arguments available in the context dictionary, and returns the desired execution dates to query. Either execution_delta or execution_date_fn can be passed to ExternalTaskSensor, but not both.

You could define the sensor like this:

```py
    wait_for_dag_a = ExternalTaskSensor(
        task_id='wait_for_dag_a',
        external_task_id="external_task_1",
        external_dag_id='dag_a_id',
        allowed_states=['success', 'failed'],
        execution_date_fn=_get_execution_date_of_dag_a,
        poke_interval=30
    )
```

Where `_get_execution_date_of_dag_a` performs a query to the DB using `get_last_dagrun` allowing you to get the last `execution_date` of *DAG_A*.

```py
from airflow.utils.db import provide_session
from airflow.models.dag import get_last_dagrun

@provide_session
def _get_execution_date_of_dag_a(exec_date, session=None,  **kwargs):
    dag_a_last_run = get_last_dagrun(
        'dag_a_id', session)
    return dag_a_last_run.execution_date
```

I hope this approach helps you out. You can find a working example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67765204/10569220).

Comment: do you know if it is possible to change _get_execution_date_of_dag_a func, to allow a parameter to dynamically get the last run for different dag_ids?

Comment: I figured it out!
`<
@provide_session
def get_last_run_lambda(exteral_dag_id, session):
    dag_last_run = get_last_dagrun(exteral_dag_id, session)
    last_exec_date = dag_last_run.execution_date
    return lambda x: last_exec_date
>`

Answer (score 3):

Combining [@Gonza Piotti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2520301/gonza-piotti)'s comment with [@NicoE](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10569220/nicoe)'s answer:

```py
from airflow.utils.db import provide_session
from airflow.models.dag import get_last_dagrun

def _get_execution_date_of(dag_id):
    @provide_session
    def _get_last_execution_date(exec_date, session=None, **kwargs):
        dag_a_last_run = get_last_dagrun(dag_id, session)
        return dag_a_last_run.execution_date
    return _get_last_execution_date
```

we get a function that will yield another function which computes the last execution date of a given `dag_id`, use it like:

```py
    wait_for_dag_a = ExternalTaskSensor(
        task_id='wait_for_dag_a',
        external_task_id='external_task_1',
        external_dag_id='dag_a',
        allowed_states=['success', 'failed'],
        execution_date_fn=_get_execution_date_of('dag_a'),
        poke_interval=30
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

To enrich [@Guilherme Z. Santos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7046260/guilherme-z-santos)' answer, I suggest adding `include_externally_triggered=True` to the `get_last_dagrun` call.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35514605)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).